# Capybara no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

Tags: ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, capybara, rspec-rails

Capybara is raising this strange error, the first example always works fine, but the subsequent ones fail with this same error when calling the visit method the second time during execution:

> TypeError:
> 'no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer'

I have tried bundle updates, changing my mocks around but nothing seems do change anything.
I have no idea how to reproduce it, because I don't know how it happens.

- Problem first appeared after upgrading from rails 3.2 to 5.2
- The test environment is raising errors and Capybara is passing them on normally.
- All tests pass individually.
- It happens always on the second visit call regardless of whether it's in the same example or not

## I've tried:

- `selenium` and `selenium_chrome` as well as the headless variants
- checking the `before(:each)` block
- running `bundle update --conservative` and `bundle update`
- adding `config.raise_server_errors` in Capybara config
- different `selenium-webdriver` versions

Edit1: Only happens with `js: true` tests

Traceback:

```
Editar Documentação
  Editar Documentação
    com falha
      documentação adicional não entregue
Capybara starting Puma...
* Version 4.3.1 , codename: Mysterious Traveller
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 4
* Listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:37485
        não consegue editar de pendente para indeferido
    com sucesso
      indeferido para deferido
        consegue editar de indeferido para deferido (FAILED - 1)
      pendente para indeferido
        consegue editar de pendente para indeferido (FAILED - 2)

Failures:

  1) Editar Documentação Editar Documentação com sucesso indeferido para deferido consegue editar de indeferido para deferido
     Failure/Error: visit edit_candidatura_path(candidatura)
     
     TypeError:
       no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
     # /home/gurja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@sispos_novo/gems/capybara-3.32.1/lib/capybara/session.rb:271:in `[]='
     # /home/gurja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@sispos_novo/gems/capybara-3.32.1/lib/capybara/session.rb:271:in `visit'
     # /home/gurja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@sispos_novo/gems/capybara-3.32.1/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:58:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
     # ./spec/features/candidatos/editar_documentacao_spec.rb:41:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Editar Documentação Editar Documentação com sucesso pendente para indeferido consegue editar de pendente para indeferido
     Failure/Error: visit edit_candidatura_path(candidatura)
     
     TypeError:
       no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
     # /home/gurja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@sispos_novo/gems/capybara-3.32.1/lib/capybara/session.rb:271:in `[]='
     # /home/gurja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@sispos_novo/gems/capybara-3.32.1/lib/capybara/session.rb:271:in `visit'
     # /home/gurja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@sispos_novo/gems/capybara-3.32.1/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:58:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
     # ./spec/features/candidatos/editar_documentacao_spec.rb:73:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

Top 3 slowest examples (15.28 seconds, 89.3% of total time):
  Editar Documentação Editar Documentação com falha documentação adicional não entregue não consegue editar de pendente para indeferido
    10.53 seconds ./spec/features/candidatos/editar_documentacao_spec.rb:106
  Editar Documentação Editar Documentação com sucesso indeferido para deferido consegue editar de indeferido para deferido
    2.43 seconds ./spec/features/candidatos/editar_documentacao_spec.rb:40
  Editar Documentação Editar Documentação com sucesso pendente para indeferido consegue editar de pendente para indeferido
    2.32 seconds ./spec/features/candidatos/editar_documentacao_spec.rb:72

Finished in 17.11 seconds (files took 5 seconds to load)
3 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/features/candidatos/editar_documentacao_spec.rb:40 # Editar Documentação Editar Documentação com sucesso indeferido para deferido consegue editar de indeferido para deferido
rspec ./spec/features/candidatos/editar_documentacao_spec.rb:72 # Editar Documentação Editar Documentação com sucesso pendente para indeferido consegue editar de pendente para indeferido
```

Capybara config:

```rb
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome)
end

Capybara.register_driver :headless_chrome do |app|
  capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
    chromeOptions: { args: %w(headless disable-gpu) }
  )
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, { browser: :chrome, desired_capabilities: capabilities })
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :chrome

Capybara.configure do |config|
  config.raise_server_errors
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each, js: true) do
    Capybara.page.driver.browser.manage.window.maximize
  end
end
```

Gemfile:

```rb
ruby '2.5.3'

# Aplicações Gerais
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2'
gem 'rake', '13.0.1'
# gem 'rack-cache'
gem 'mysql2', '0.5.2'
gem 'cancancan', '3.0.2'
gem 'nokogiri', '1.10.8'
# gem 'exception_notification', '2.6.1', :require => 'exception_notifier'
gem 'acts_as_votable', '0.12.1'
gem 'time_splitter', '1.1.0'
gem 'httparty', '0.17.3'
# gem 'rails-erd', '1.5.2', require: false
# gem 'sprockets-rails', :require => 'sprockets/railtie'
gem 'iconv', '1.0.8'
gem 'has_scope', '0.7.2'
gem 'font-awesome-rails', '4.7.0.5'
gem 'responders', '~> 2.0'

# JSON
gem 'json', '2.3.0'
gem 'multi_json', '~> 1.14', '>= 1.14.1'

# JQuery
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.3.5'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '6.0.1'
# gem 'bxslider-rails'
gem 'select2-rails', '4.0.3'
gem 'multi-select-rails', '0.9.12'

# Javascript
gem 'js-routes', '1.4.9'
gem 'therubyracer', '0.12.3'
# gem 'highcharts-rails'
gem 'sprockets', '3.7.2'
gem 'uglifier', '4.2.0'

# Query
gem 'will_paginate', '3.1.7'

# ActiveRecord
gem 'paperclip', '6.1.0'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record', '4.1.4'
gem 'amoeba', '3.1.0'
gem 'activeresource', '5.1.0'

# Validations
gem 'validates_timeliness', '4.1.1'
gem 'charlock_holmes_bundle_icu', '~> 0.6.9.2'
# gem 'rqrcode'

# Documentos
gem 'spreadsheet', '1.2.6'
gem 'to_xls', '1.5.3'
gem 'rtf', '0.3.3'
gem 'prawn', '2.2.2'
gem 'prawn-table', '0.2.2'
gem 'prawn-qrcode', '0.5.1'

# Ruby
# gem 'whenever'
# gem 'daemons', '1.0.10'
# gem 'websocket', '1.2.1'
# gem 'concurrent-ruby'

# GrayLog
gem 'gelf', '3.1.0'

# Assets Pipeline
gem 'sass-rails', '6.0.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '5.0.0'
gem 'tinymce-rails', '5.2.0'
gem 'highcharts-rails', '6.0.3'

# Migracao para o docker
gem 'puma', '4.3.1'

# Acertos
gem 'rubocop', require: false

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'uniform_notifier', '1.13.0'
  gem 'factory_bot_rails', '5.1.1'
  # gem 'awesome_print'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'rails3-generators'
  # gem 'mongrel', '1.2.0.pre2'
  # gem 'email_spec', '1.5.0'
  # gem 'public_suffix', '1.4.6'
  # gem 'webrick', '~> 1.3.1'
end

group :development do
  gem 'bullet'
  gem 'brakeman', :require => false
end

group :test do
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'database_cleaner', '1.7.0'
  # gem 'launchy'
  gem 'webmock'
  # # gem "activerecord-mysql2-retry-ext"
  gem 'simplecov'
  gem 'simplecov-rcov'
  # gem 'transpec'
  # gem 'parser', '2.3.3.1'
end

group :production, :homologacao do
  gem 'SyslogLogger'
  # gem 'newrelic_rpm'
end

group :development, :test, :homologacao do
  gem 'letter_opener'
end
```

editar_documentacao_spec.rb:

```rb
# coding: UTF-8
require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.feature 'Editar Documentação', type: :feature do
  let(:admin) { create :administrador_suporte }
  let(:iduff) { admin.vinculacao.identificacao_login.iduff }

  let(:candidato) { create :candidato }
  let(:deferido) { create :situacao_documentacao, :deferido }
  let(:indeferido) { create :situacao_documentacao, :indeferido }
  let(:pendente) { create :situacao_documentacao, :pendente }

  let(:cpf_xpath) { '//*[@id="edit_candidatura_1"]/fieldset[2]/div[1]/span[2]/input' }
  let(:rg_xpath) { '//*[@id="edit_candidatura_1"]/fieldset[2]/div[2]/span[2]/input' }
  let(:diploma_xpath) { '//*[@id="edit_candidatura_1"]/fieldset[2]/div[3]/div/div/span[2]/input' }
  let(:documentao_adicional_xpath) { '//*[@id="doc_adicional"]/span/input' }

  before(:each) do
    deferido
    indeferido
    pendente
    candidatura
    situacao

    login_user(iduff)
  end

  describe 'Editar Documentação', js: true do
    context 'com sucesso' do
      context 'indeferido para deferido' do
        let(:situacao) do
          create :situacao_candidatura, :aguardando_avaliacao_desempenho
        end

        let(:candidatura) do
          create :candidatura_documentacao_indeferida, candidato: candidato
        end

        scenario 'consegue editar de indeferido para deferido' do
          visit edit_candidatura_path(candidatura)

          attach_file('candidatura_documentacoes_candidatura_attributes_0_documento',
                      "#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/documentos/cpf.pdf")
          xpath_fill_autocomplete(cpf_xpath, with: deferido.descricao)

          attach_file('candidatura_documentacoes_candidatura_attributes_1_documento',
                      "#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/documentos/rg.pdf")
          xpath_fill_autocomplete(rg_xpath, with: deferido.descricao)

          attach_file('candidatura_documentacoes_candidatura_attributes_2_documento',
                      "#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/documentos/diploma.pdf")
          xpath_fill_autocomplete(diploma_xpath, with: deferido.descricao)

          xpath_fill_autocomplete(documentao_adicional_xpath, with: deferido.descricao)

          click_on 'Salvar'

          expect(page).to have_content "Documentos Atualizados com sucesso!"
        end
      end

      context 'pendente para indeferido' do
        let(:situacao) do
          create :situacao_candidatura, :indeferido_aguardando_reenvio
        end

        let(:candidatura) do
          create :candidatura_aguardando_avaliacao, candidato: candidato
        end

        scenario 'consegue editar de pendente para indeferido' do
          visit edit_candidatura_path(candidatura)

          attach_file('candidatura_documentacoes_candidatura_attributes_0_documento',
                      "#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/documentos/cpf.pdf")
          xpath_fill_autocomplete(cpf_xpath, with: indeferido.descricao)

          attach_file('candidatura_documentacoes_candidatura_attributes_1_documento',
                      "#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/documentos/rg.pdf")
          xpath_fill_autocomplete(rg_xpath, with: indeferido.descricao)

          attach_file('candidatura_documentacoes_candidatura_attributes_2_documento',
                      "#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/documentos/diploma.pdf")
          xpath_fill_autocomplete(diploma_xpath, with: indeferido.descricao)
          
          xpath_fill_autocomplete(documentao_adicional_xpath, with: deferido.descricao)

          click_on 'Salvar'

          expect(page).to have_content "Documentos Indeferidos!"
        end
      end
    end

    context 'com falha' do
      let(:situacao) do
        create :situacao_candidatura, :indeferido_aguardando_reenvio
      end

      context 'documentação adicional não entregue' do
        let(:candidatura) do
          create :candidatura_aguardando_avaliacao, candidato: candidato
        end

        scenario 'não consegue editar de pendente para indeferido' do
          visit edit_candidatura_path(candidatura)

          attach_file('candidatura_documentacoes_candidatura_attributes_0_documento',
                      "#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/documentos/cpf.pdf")
          xpath_fill_autocomplete(cpf_xpath, with: indeferido.descricao)

          attach_file('candidatura_documentacoes_candidatura_attributes_1_documento',
                      "#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/documentos/rg.pdf")
          xpath_fill_autocomplete(rg_xpath, with: indeferido.descricao)

          attach_file('candidatura_documentacoes_candidatura_attributes_2_documento',
                      "#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/documentos/diploma.pdf")
          xpath_fill_autocomplete(diploma_xpath, with: indeferido.descricao)

          click_on 'Salvar'

          expect(page).to have_content "Documentação adicional não entregue!"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the contents of     ./spec/features/candidatos/editar_documentacao_spec.rb - the offending line is Line 41 - it's important to know what that line and that function contains.

Comment: I've edited the question to include the file. Nothing seems wrong with the tests, other files show the same behavior: first example executed passes and others fail with the TypeError

Comment: Looking at the line in Capybara the error is reporting from, it shouldn’t be possible unless something is monkey patching one of the objects. The fact the error doesn’t happen on the first test means whatever is causing the issue is happening between tests, so what are you running in RSpec `after` blocks?

Comment: there are no after blocks, and it still happens if I call visit twice inside an example

Comment: Did you jump straight from 3.2 to 5.2? It's advised to go in increments when upgrading Rails, not 2 major versions at once.

Comment: Yes, it was my team's decision

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it. It was something with Capybara's version in my project, probably a package version conflict since I haven't found this problem anywhere else in Stackoverflow or Capybara's Github issues.

## Solution:

I downgraded it to 3.10.1 and it worked, then I incrementally upgraded it until 3.15.1. Any version newer than this broke.